# as3 image over another using bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok so im trying to load a bitmap image as a background using this:

```
screenBitmapData.copyPixels(tilesBitmapData,new Rectangle(sourceX,sourceY,tileSize,tileSize),new Point(destX,destY));
screenBitmap = new Bitmap(screenBitmapData);
addChild(screenBitmap);
```

This load my tiled map correctly and display it on the screen.

Now i want to add another image which will be used as my character and the frame displaying it contain my character movement and then display the image as follow:

```
screenBitmapData.copyPixels(playerSheetBitmapData, new Rectangle(currentSpriteColumn * CHAR_SPRITE_WIDTH, currentSpriteRow * CHAR_SPRITE_HEIGHT, CHAR_SPRITE_WIDTH, CHAR_SPRITE_HEIGHT), new Point(xPos, yPos), null, null,true);
```

I setted the alpha channel on my character image and this is the result when im moving around my map with it:

http://snag.gy/L2uuR.jpg

As you can see, the background image doesnt refresh. And i simply dont know how to do this. Im pretty new with flash and as3 and ive been trying for days to make it work. I know it have something to do with the copypixel or redrawing the background before i draw the sprite again... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redraw the entire scene. All you're doing at the moment is drawing the player ontop of the result of your previous draw.

All you need to do in your case is draw the entire background each frame before you draw the character. It could look like this:

```
function renderScene():void
{
    // Draw the background, which will replace all the current graphics
    // on the Bitmap.
    screenBitmapData.copyPixels(tilesBitmapData,new Rectangle(sourceX,sourceY,tileSize,tileSize),new Point(destX,destY));

    // Then draw the player.
    screenBitmapData.copyPixels(playerSheetBitmapData, new Rectangle(currentSpriteColumn * CHAR_SPRITE_WIDTH, currentSpriteRow * CHAR_SPRITE_HEIGHT, CHAR_SPRITE_WIDTH, CHAR_SPRITE_HEIGHT), new Point(xPos, yPos), null, null,true);
}
```

To actually clear the Bitmap though, you can just use [`fillRect()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#fillRect%28%29) to fill it with a color (e.g. black):

```
// Fill the Bitmap with black.
screenBitmapData.fillRect( screenBitmapData.rect, 0x000000 );
```

Comment: Ok i tryed to load my whole function that load the map before the sprite and it worked well! But you can imagine i got a massive lag issue after walking for 5 second since a whole map is loaded from xml each time and redrawing square by square on the image.Is there any way to just specify my image to redraw itself without going trough all my processus? or maybe unload the child and just reload it ?

Comment: @Aenil Yes, you should not be loading the graphic more than once. I would break your game down into two parts: 1) the loading phase where all your graphics are loaded. Once loaded, you will store reference to each piece of BitmapData. 2) begin the actual game, which will deal with copying the pixels over to your main Bitmap. This phase will begin only when phase 1 is complete (all the assets have loaded and been stored for use).